# Seasonal component for a series that is only one and a half years

Tags: trend, seasonality

I have a times series for temperature and I am trying to decompose it into a

seasonal + trend + stochastic process

to look at what model would fit for the stochastic process.

However, I only have data for 333 days, and I assume my data should include a periodic phenomena, with the period being one year, or 365 days. How can I eliminate the trend and seasonal component when I don't have data for the entire assumed period? Is there a way to implement the method in R?

Here is the series
http://www.wikiupload.com/XD5FHJFC7S857MG

EDIT: Plot of this data by @Penguin_Knight

[image]

Comment: Why is 333 days "one and a half year?"

Comment: Edited, my mistake, sorry about that

Comment: Huh? Where are the data in February, March, and first half of April?

Comment: I just post this graph here for other users to better understand the problem. The duration of record is more than a year, but the actual number of cases is only 333.

Comment: I can't believe that it's possible to calculate a seasonal effect for a data set that does not include each season more than once. Much less a data set that doesn't have any data from roughly three months of the year.

Comment: Yes, there also seem to be missing values. What kind of interpolation is appropriate, or even forecasting to fill in the missing blanks?

Comment: How did you otherwise make that plot Knight? What condition did you write to check for missing values, i.e. how did you search for the missing values

Comment: @l3win Because there is a date variable in your data, you can just use the first day as seq = 1, and then for each increment of calendar date, the seq increases by 1. There is a jump of 75 in the Feb/Mar/Apr session, and hence, there is no corresponding data points. I used SPSS datediff() function to make the seq variable.

Comment: @l3win I am not well versed with analyzing incomplete time series, so please take my comments accordingly. I felt that you need more data. The fact that V3 is at the same level before and after the gap indicates the seasonality my be more complicated that one peak. There could be a secondary peak some where in the gap. And also a little one at seq = 25 to 35. I'm not sure if the current length of the series is enough to inform you anything about the seasonal pattern.

Comment: You are correct, @Wayne: it is impossible, because season and "trend" are completely confounded; there is no information to separate one from the other.

Comment: I fear that without some heroic assumptions (unverifiable from this data and possibly difficult to justify), meaningful progress will be impossible.

Comment: I have another question related to this series. If I want to find the cross-correlation between this temperature series and another series, do I have to make each series series stationary before I look at the correlation?

Comment: @Penguin_Knight I have converted your extension into an edit; please use this feature in the future. Thanks!